# automatic collapse grouped rows when closing file

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am having trouble with a sheets file. I have grouped rows at different levels, and I want them to collapse every time I close (or open) the file.

I am not familiar with script apps or javascript or any other programming language.
I envision a code that finds rows that are grouped together and reduces each group.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a code like this, that gets all the rows from the sheet and collapse the existing groups:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getMaxRows()).collapseGroups()
}
```

[image]

---

UPDATE

If you need the code to apply to every sheet, you can try with:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheets[i].getRange(1, 1, sheets[i].getMaxRows()).collapseGroups()
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi ! thank you very much ! I'm not familiar with codes AND I'm french, so not easy to find my words. Your code works perfectly ! If I can ask more, I have several sheets and I need this code to work on each. Should I copy this code and replace "sheet1" with each of my sheets or is it possible to have it collapse groups in all sheets in one time ? thanks again !

Comment: I added an update in my response!